# how to pass the javascript variable value to <portlet:param/> in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2 community, i want to create link using renderrequest. I have code like this :

```
<script>
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var myUrl = "<portlet:renderURL var='renderOneUrl'> "+
            "<portlet:param name='action' value='renderOne' />"+
            "<portlet:param name='id' value='"+i+"' /></portlet:renderURL>"+
            "<a href='${renderOneUrl}'> Click to call render method</a>";
    $("div.link").append(myUrl);
}
</script>
```

and this is for java code :

```
@RenderMapping(params = "action=renderOne")
public String handleRenderOneRequest(RenderRequest request,RenderResponse response,Model model){
 System.out.println("akh akh");
 String id = request.getParameter("id");
 System.out.println("id = "+id);
 //var id always received i not '0/1/2/3/etc'
 return "detail";
}
```

My question is why value form `<portlet:param name='id' value='"+i+"' />` always received i (the name of that variable), not value form that js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scriptlet combines server-side and client-side processing in a way that doesn't make sense. You try to use JSP tag `portlet:renderURL` with JavaScript variable `i` as parameter.

Fortunately, the portlet urls can be created in JavaScript.

```
<script>
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var myUrl = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
    myUrl.setParameter('action', 'renderOne');
    myUrl.setParameter('id', i);

    var link = "<a href='" + myUrl.toString() + "'>Click to call render method</a>";
    $("div.link").append(link);
}
```

See [Creating Portlet URLs in JavaScript](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-portlet-urls-in-javascript-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-07-en) for details.